# CSS Zoom in and out on mouse click and scroll down or up zoomed image when paga scroll up or down

Tags: css

```css
.click-zoom input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none
}

.click-zoom img {
  margin: 100px;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease;
  cursor: zoom-in
}

.click-zoom input[type=checkbox]:checked~img {
  transform: scale(2);
  cursor: zoom-out
}
```

```html
<div class="click-zoom">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
  </label>
</div>
```

When i click on image i get image zoomed, but it is not centered (horizontally and vertically)...i try adding position: absolute; but then image is tool large on screen.

Also i need whenimage on click is zoomed to scroll down or up when page scroll down or up...how can i do this in css?

Comment: Are you just wanting the image itself to be centered? As for the scrolling part, are you saying you can only use CSS for it? Or there's possibility to use javascript like [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)?

Comment: I can use jQuery code so if you could point me to the code or library that does what i need.